# Query in wikidata: how to store labels for different languages in different variables

Tags: sparql, wikidata

trying to query  [wikidata](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3FitemLabel1%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20p%3AP17%20%3Fstatement0.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fstatement0%20%28ps%3AP17%2F%28wdt%3AP279%2A%29%29%20wd%3AQ155.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20p%3AP31%20%3Fstatement1.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fstatement1%20%28ps%3AP31%2F%28wdt%3AP279%2A%29%29%20wd%3AQ207524.%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fitem%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FitemLabel%20filter%20%28lang%28%3Flabel%29%20%3D%20%22pt%22%29%20.%20%7D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fitem%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3FitemLabel1%20filter%20%28lang%28%3Flabel%29%20%3D%20%22ceb%22%29%20.%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%0A%7D)
currently, the code saves only in one variable itemLabel  labels for listed languages in a certain order: if no Portuguese, use the Cebuano label instead, if no Cebuano - use English or [auto_language] (Which also means English):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel ?lang WHERE {
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "pt,ceb,en, [AUTO_LANGUAGE]". }
  {
    SELECT DISTINCT ?item WHERE {
      ?item p:P17 ?statement0.
      ?statement0 (ps:P17/(wdt:P279*)) wd:Q155.
      ?item p:P31 ?statement1.
      ?statement1 (ps:P31/(wdt:P279*)) wd:Q207524.
    }
  }
}
```

What I'm looking for - having Portuguese in one column, Cebuano in another, and English in the other

I've also tried

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel ?itemLabel1 WHERE {
      ?item p:P17 ?statement0.
      ?statement0 (ps:P17/(wdt:P279*)) wd:Q155.
      ?item p:P31 ?statement1.
      ?statement1 (ps:P31/(wdt:P279*)) wd:Q207524.
  OPTIONAL { ?item rdfs:label ?itemLabel filter (lang(?itemLabel) = "pt") . }
  OPTIONAL { ?item rdfs:label ?itemLabel1 filter (lang(?itemLabel1) = "ceb") . }
    
  
}
```

But the returned result is null :(

Could it be solved, what do you think? ;)

Comment: what do you mean by "could it be solved"? You used an `OPTIONAL` pattern, and if there is no such label in the given language then sure, the result will be `null` aka empty aka no binding. Check both items in the browser, click on "All entered languages" at the top to see all available labels. For one island there is only Cebuano for the other only the Portuguese lang - there is nothing to solve here, the data is just missing in your case. Quite common that not all labels are avaibable in all languages. The good thing is, it's Wikidata - you could contribute if you know additional labels.

Comment: meanwhile I've found the issue (basically typo ) in the second query and fixed it. All said is indeed correct. Thanks for the interest :)

Comment: ok, I didn't catch your edit - you should have close your question if you found the typo and there wasn't any issue anymore. I mean, your edited query works as expected, it 's just a lack of data which you already knew I guess.